# is it good to always give parameter spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark application. It sometime goes down (once or twice in a month) due to executor out of memory. Will giving spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead going to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executor running out of memory may be happening beacause of:

- HIGH CONCURRENCY
- INEFFICIENT QUERIES
- INCORRECT CONFIGURATION

Each application’s memory requirement is different. Depending on the requirement, each app has to be configured differently.

According to [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/running-on-yarn.html):

> `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` is the amount of off-heap memory
>   (in megabytes) to be allocated per executor. This is memory that
>   accounts for things like VM overheads, interned strings, other native
>   overheads, etc. This tends to grow with the executor size (typically
>   6-10%).

Hence, in cases like yours,it is generally recommended to increase the Spark executor Memory and if running in Yarn, its recommended to increase the overhead memory as well to avoid OOM(Out of memory) issues as overhead memory is used for JVM threads, internal metadata etc.

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: yes sure it helped in increasing my understanding. By the way what's the default value for spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead ? 
I see in my application its not initialized, So i will have this parameter too.
I assume its always good to have this parameter. Right? @Anand Sai

Comment: Yeah, in most cases, it's good to have parameter. But, you need to careful as not set properly, it might increase cost or throw errors.